# Function name conflict when including a PHP file in a WordPress Theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a PHP novice, so bear with me if any of my terminology is incorrect.

I have a small PHP file (`page_class.php`) that defines some functions and I include this file in the header.php of my theme:

```
<?php include("page_class.php"); ?>
```

And these are the contents of `page_class.php`:

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}

function get_subdomain() {
    $page_url = curPageURL();
    $parts = split('\.', $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]);
    return $parts[0];
}

function get_body_class() {
    $subdomain = get_subdomain();
    if ($subdomain == "keyes") {
        $path_parts = split('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
        $clazz = $path_parts[1];
    }
    else {
        $clazz = $subdomain;
    }
    if ($clazz == "greasemonkey" || $clazz == "wordpress") {
        $clazz = "work";
    }
    if ($clazz == "") {
        $clazz = "home";
    }
    return $clazz;
}
?>
```

I call `get_body_class` in `header.php`:

```
<body class="<?php echo get_body_class(); ?>">
```

This setup worked in WordPress MU 2.7.1.  I recently upgraded to 2.8.6 and it broke.  When I visited any page on the blog the screen was blank.

After some investigation I figured out that by changing the function names (I prefixed them with `jk_`) it worked again.

I guessed this was a naming conflict, but couldn't find any.  I wonder do any PHP or WordPress devs have any idea why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_body_class()` [seems in fact to be there since 2.8](http://xref.yoast.com/trunk/nav.html?wp-includes/post-template.php.source.html#l360). You're not the only one who had the problem: See [here](http://www.nathanrice.net/blog/wordpress-2-8-and-the-body_class-function/).

By the way, while it is the right thing to have error reporting turned off on a production server, you may want to turn it up some if you get errors like that.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: Now sure how my `find grep` missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've just downloaded the sources of wordpress 2.9 (not exactly the same version as yours, I admit, but it's the last one, and the easiest to get from wordpress.org), and it seems there is already an existing `get_body_class` function :

```
$ grep -rn 'get_body_class' *
wp-includes/post-template.php:354:      echo 'class="' . join( ' ', get_body_class( $class ) ) . '"';
wp-includes/post-template.php:365:function get_body_class( $class = '' ) {
```

It seems that function is defined in `post-template.php` *(line 365 in wordpress 2.9)* ; which explains the conflict, as it's not possible to have two functions with the same name, in PHP.

Comment: Thanks Pascal. Not sure how my `find grep` missed that. Must have been a typo. I think Stack Overflow need to introduce an Embarrassed badge for me :)

Comment: you're welcome :-) maybe you didn't grep recursively, or something like that ?

Comment: I use find for recursive grepping `find . -name "*.php" -exec grep -H get_body_class {} \;` Who knows? Either way, I shall grep twice before posting from now on :)

Comment: googling "functionname wordpress" is a good additional measure. :)

Comment: @Pekka : indeed ^^ but not as fun ;-)